# Как сконвертировать несколько ImageView в 1 Canvas/Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

Есть следующая задача. На экране есть область, где могут размещаться `ImageView`. Разместить их можно бесконечно и все они размещаются в одном `layout` (`RelativeLayout`). Далее, необходимо конвертировать все `ImageView` с экрана в один `Bitmap` заданного размера (Размер может быть больше размера экрана). Собственно, как это реализовать?

Здесь ещё важно учитывать, что все `ImageView` могут быть по-разному повернуты.

В голову пока приходит лишь одна незаконченная идея: Конвертировать `background` родительского `layout` в `Bitmap`, затем, отслеживая позиции других дочерних элементов относительно родительского, конвертить дочерние `ImageView` в `Bitmap` и размещать этот `Bitmap` поверх родительского `Bitmap` (Который сделан от `background`)

Кстати, ещё вопрос. Если у `ImageView` есть только `background`, можно ли от этого `ImageView` получить `Bitmap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

таким образом можно получить битмап любого лэйаута (дочерние тоже будут отображены). если битмап должен быть больше экрана, то скорее всего придется делать то что Вы описали.

```
RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativelayout);
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bm = view.getDrawingCache();
```